# Please open my PC and read me yours windows 10 setup for environment variables PATH

Tags: variables, path, windows-10, environment

I accidentally deleted my PATHs. Now "npm start" doesn't work. Can anyone with node.js installed on their PC, with Win10, see what he has and tell me.

1. Please go to my Computer / my PC
2. second mouse click - then Properties
3. Click on Advanced system settings
4. click Advanced Tab, then click Environment Variables
5. Under System variables click on PATH then Edit...
6. Please write down here all the PATH's you have

...something like
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Windows\system32
etc...

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm ?

Comment: I don't know. All I have is:

C:\Python38-32\Scripts\
C:\Python38-32
C:\Python38-32\airline
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem

some are obviously missing...
I suppose 
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm 
is one of them

can you read all you have please

Comment: Did u add it with ur username instead of "Name"?

Comment: Ok, i looked over my PATH's again opened the Location on my PC and saw, that there is nothing in that npm Location.. idk why it got created by Windows

Comment: can I add global paths like C:\ or D:\, and remove the rest

Comment: So my npm shows this Location C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm but its actually not even in my PATH Variables, Is npm in your node_modules Folder?

Comment: I just remembered that I rewrite Path when installing Python.

What is npm command to echo PATH and set new? maybe that's the error

Comment: When I type in cmd "echo %PATH%" I got these: C:\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Python38-32;C:\Python38-32\airline;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Users\KK\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\KK\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\KK\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\KK\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\KK\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\KK\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 0):

So I install fresh windows 10, update windows, installed node.js, and VS code.

THIS IS THE ENV. VAR. PATH'S - NOW EVERYTHING IS WORKING!!!

C:\Python38\Scripts
C:\Python38
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin